# Processes and a shared file descriptor

Tags: c

I have an application that creates multiple instances (processes) of itself and these processes have a shared data structure. In that struct there is a file descriptor used for logging data to file. There is a check in the logging function that checks to see if the file descriptor  is -1 and if it is then it opens the file and sets the value of the shared file descriptor.

Other processes / threads do the same check but at this time the fd is != -1. So the file does not get opened. They then continue to writing to the file. The write fails most of the time and returns -1.  When the write did not fail I checked the file path of the fd using readlink. The path was some other file than the log file.

I am assuming that this is because even though the file descriptor value was always 11, even in subsequent runs, that value refers to a different file for each process. So it is the eleventh file that process has open? So the log file is not even regarded as open for these processes and even if they do open the file the fd would be different.

So my question is this correct? My second question is how do I then re-implement this method given that multiple processes need to write to this log file. Would each process need to open that file.. or is there another way that is more efficient.. do I need to close the file so that other processes can open and write to it..?

EDIT:

The software is an open source software called filebench.
The file can be seen  [here](https://github.com/dbrashear/filebench/blob/master/misc.c).

Log method is filebench_log. Line 204 is the first check I mentioned where the file is opened. The write happens at line 293. The fd value is eleven among all processes and the value is the same: 11. It is actually shared through all processes and setup mostly [here](https://github.com/aboSamoor/Filebench/blob/master/go_filebench-1.4.8.fsl.0.7/ipc.c).  The file is only opened once (verified via print statements).

The shared data struct that has the fd is called

```
filebench_shm
```

and the fd is

```
filebench_shm->shm_log_fd
```

EDIT 2: 
The error message that I get is Bad file descriptor. Errno is 9.

EDIT 3: 
So it seems that each process has a different index table for the fds. Wiki:

`On Linux, the set of file descriptors open in a process can be accessed under the path /proc/PID/fd/, where PID is the process identifier.`

So the issue that I am having is that for two processes with process IDs 101, 102 the file descriptor 11 is not the same for the two processes:

```
/proc/101/fd/11 
/proc/102/fd/11
```

I have a shared data structure between these processes.. is there another way I can share an open file between them other than an fd since that doesn't work?

Comment: "*write fails most of the time and returns -1*" and `errno` is set to which value?

Comment: "*creates multiple instances*" how?

Comment: Some code would be helpful.  Do note, however, that unless you have placed the structure in shared memory, it is *not* shared among multiple processes.  When you spawn child processes, each one gets its own *copy*.of everything else (supposing you start the new copies by `fork()`ing).

Comment: "*shared data structure*" how?

Comment: The platform all this is happening on would also be interesting.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that it would be simplest to open the file before spawning the new processes.  This avoids all the coordination complexity regarding opening the file by centralizing it to one time and place.

Comment: I called the log method in the ipc_init where it is initializing all the shared data structures and before any other processes are created. Still same issue. It seems that for each process the fd results in either file not found or it ends up writing to a different file where that different file is different for each process.

Comment: "*writing to a different file*" how do these files differs?

Comment: I do this readlink("/proc/self/fd/11", filepath, 300);  . As I mentioned the value of fd is always 11. The first time it prints the correct path for the log file and writes to the file. Most times it is an empty string so nothing gets printed and I get errno =9. Other times I get a variation of /fist/upper/bigfileset/00000002/00000001 such as /fist/upper/bigfileset/00000002/000000013. Since this is a filebench software it creates a bunch of files / directories. Note: I do not hard code the fd=11 anywhere except in the method above.

Answer (score 2):

I originally wrote this as a solution:

> - Create a shared memory segment.
> - Put the file descriptor variable in the segment.
> - Put a mutex semaphore in the segment
> - Each process accesses the file descriptor in the segment.  If it is not open, lock the semaphore, check if it is open, and if not open the
>   file.  Release the mutex.
>
> That way all processes share the same file descriptor.

But this assumes that the the underlying file descriptor object is also in the shared memory, which I think it is not.

Instead, use the `open` then `fork` method mentioned in the other answer, or have each process open the file and use `flock` to serialize access when needed.

Comment: This is what is happening except with no locks. As I mentioned in the post the fd value is 11 for all processes. However, when I print the filepath, each process either prints a different file or nothing since each process has a different set of files open.

Comment: That is why the lock is needed.

Comment: I added a lock and that did not help. If you check the first link in the edit I added   (void) ipc_mutex_lock(&filebench_shm->shm_msg_lock); at line 202 and unlocked it after the if block. That unfortunately did not fix it.

Comment: These steps "*If it is not open, lock the semaphore, check if it is open*" seem to have gotten a bit out of order. 1st lock the semaphore then check if it's open, no need to check again if it's open, then do the rest as per your answer.

Comment: @alk - checking if it is already open avoids locking, which is expensive.

Comment: Ah dang, you are right. Sry. However it's good to have this mentioned explicitly, isn't it? ;-)

Comment: Well as I mentioned I added the lock even before the check and that still did not work..